# Edit customer shipping address on checkout - magento 2

Tags: javascript, php, knockout.js, magento2, checkout

Wanted to know how to add edit field for the original shipping address which is provided under customer account and also edit the address properly. Have been checking the magento functionality and documentation and don't know how to properly come up with the solution. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The template is vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html. You can override this template by copying this file to your theme folder in Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html.

```
<div class="shipping-address-item" css="'selected-item' : isSelected() , 'not-selected-item':!isSelected()">
    <text args="address().prefix"/> <text args="address().firstname"/> <text args="address().middlename"/>
    <text args="address().lastname"/> <text args="address().suffix"/><br/>
    <text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"/><br/>
    <text args="address().city "/>, <span text="address().region"></span> <text args="address().postcode"/><br/>
    <text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"/><br/>
    <a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>

<each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
    <text args="$parent.getCustomAttributeLabel(element)"/>
    <br/>
</each>

<button visible="address().isEditable()" type="button"
        class="action edit-address-link"
        click="editAddress">
    <span translate="'Edit'"></span>
</button>
<!-- ko if: (!isSelected()) -->
<button type="button" click="selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
    <span translate="'Ship Here'"></span>
</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And the JS file is vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.js. You can override this javascript by copying this file to your theme folder in Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.js or use mixins to extend the JavaScript (see: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html)

I see, the isEditable() function on the address is true for new addresses and false for existing addresses (see vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/new-customer-address.js and vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/model/customer/address.js) where the isEditable method returns true or false. You can try to override or extend this file and return always true and check if this works.

vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/model/customer/address.js:

```
        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        isEditable: function () {
            return false;
        },
```

Maybe another solution is to get the address ID and link the "edit" links for the existing addresses to: customer/address/edit/{id} but I'm not thinking if this is what you want because then you will leave the checkout.

Comment: I've tried the above way, now it's editable in the shipping address on checkout page, but the pop-up address values are not populated, I hope in  checkout module /address-renderer/default.js we need write some custom code in this, do you have a any idea about the code to populate the address on the shipping address pop-up ?